# .NET Core: C# Environment.GetFolderPath not defined

Tags: c#, function, system, environment

I was trying to search for a possibility to get the Desktopfolder of the current user in my consoleprogram. I found this one:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Now VS brings up an failure that there is no definition for "GetFolderPath" in "Environment".

Maybe someone can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: You need to add `using System;` at the top of your class.

Comment: Or you can fully-qualify it by using `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(...)`

Comment: using System; is still added. And it still shows the marker

Comment: What profile are you running in? If you're building a universal app for a phone, or in an asp.net server profile for a web site, this might not be included.

Comment: It's a console app .net core

Comment: and thats it.. I should have used it as a .net consoleapplication only and not the core. Because it won't work on other Plattforms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade your project to using .net Core 2.0 (.net Standard 2.0). The function is available there, but not in earlier versions.

Alternatively, you can use a normal .net console application project instead of a .net Core project, but that will not be platform independent.

Note: Although .net Standard 2.0 supports `System.Environment.GetFolderPath`it might not provide a meaningful result for all possible parameter values on all platforms and even throw an Exception on some platforms for some parameter values.

Answer (score 1):

There're two solutions(better to use 1st):

1. You need to add using to make your code see System namespace.

   ```
   using System;
   ```
2. You need to write the whole name.

   ```
   string desktopPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
   ```

Don't forget to add System reference into your project. Actually, he's there by default.

Comment: unfortunately this is not defined in .net core, irrespective of the using being added

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile");
```

That gives you the path to the user profile, Desktop is a child folder of it.